# Filtering in Sharepoint 2010 Dataview webpart - NOT WORKING

Tags: web-services, rest, sharepoint-2010, dataviewwebpart

We have a data-view webpart in Sharepoint 2010. The datasource for this webpart is third-party REST based web services. The data is displayed properly.
The problem we are facing is **sharepoint default filtering functionality is not working.**
When table header is clicked for filtering drop-down, no values are shown(as part of filter) even though the column has multiple values.

Has anyone faced such a problem with dataview webpart for REST datasource?

Any kind of comments/suggestion on this issue will be helpful.

Regards,
Pramod

Comment: It might yield better response if you put this on http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/